# How can I find all objects that reference myObject?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, moose-technology

I have an object `myObject` and I'm not sure who's holding references to it. (I want to know because I'm reverse engineering something.)

I found the button "Objects pointing to this value" in the inspector, but it doesn't bring up anything, even if I make another object that's pointing, like this:

```
OrderedCollection new add: self ; inspect
```

Clearly, that button is broken! So, how can I get all referencing objects?

I'm using the Moose 4.6 image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PointerExplorer openOn: myObject` works in Pharo, but it's slightly broken in Moose 4.6. For a quick fix revert `ObjectExplorerWrapper >> icon` to the previous version `(AlainPlantec 12/6/2009 22:13)`

In Pharo/Squeak, you can use:

```
myObject pointersTo
```

Answer (score 4):

In Pharo/Squeak, you can use:
myObject pointersTo

Answer (score 0):

In Squeak 4.5

```
PointerFinder pointersTo: myObject
```

and

```
PointerExplorer new openExplorerFor: myObject
```